# Login error on Joomla 2.5.28 installation

Tags: php, authentication, joomla, joomla2.5

After installing a Joomla plugin called “Digi Template Switch” on a live server everything seemed fine until my session expired and I tried accessing the dashboard with my credentials, only this time I got a php error -

> **Fatal error: Call to undefined method JUserHelper::verifyPassword() in /home/mysite/public_html/plugins/authentication/joomla/joomla.php on line 56**

Read up on some people who have had this issue in the past and they suggested replacing the ***adminstrator, libraries and include*** folders with that from a fresh download of same Joomla version but I have installed quite a few plugins already which would make my replacing the administrator folder a little tricky.

Would really appreciate an assistance as the Joomla installation is on a live server at the moment without access to the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can download joomla version 2.5.28 and replace that file con your server, the plugins you have installed will not be touched.